# Some product images are not displayed on home page

Tags: magento2.3

On a home page, Banner images are not displayed and getting some kind of errors in the console.

[image]

Comment: you run the di:complain after showiing this error ??

Comment: yeah, I have run this command.

Comment: after showing this error ???

Comment: yeah , GET http://localhost/magento/pub/media/wysiwyg/home/home-erin.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: you run all command but not run the di:complain command after check please

Answer (score 0):

Look like you forgot to deploy static content. Please run: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` for production mode or `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`  for other modes.

Comment: Yeah, I have Already run that command.

Comment: Do these 404 files exist in Magento pub/media folder?

Comment: http://localhost/magento/pub/media/wysiwyg this folder does not exist in my pub/media.

Comment: That is strange, please extract pub/media/wysiwyg folder from Magento archive you downloaded and put it in there,

Answer (score 0):

Create Dir `pub/media/wysiwyg/home` and put all images